# Convergent sequence of real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, real-numbers

Suppose that a_n is a convergent sequence of real numbers such that lim a_n = a > 0. Then there exists a K belongs to N such that a_n > 4a/5 holds for all n is greater than or equal to K. Is it true or false? How can i show it?

Answer (score 1):

True.Take $\epsilon = a/5$.Can you continue?

Answer (score 1):

It is true.

$a_n$ is a convergent series.

For any $\epsilon >0$ there is an $N>0$ such that when $n>N, |a_n-a|<\epsilon$
let $\epsilon = \frac 15 a$

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Recall the definition of convergence of a sequence: what happens if $\epsilon = a / 5$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $\limsup_na_n=\lim_na_n=a$ by definition means that $a_n>a-\varepsilon$ if $n$ is large enough.